# strtod not giving consistent results on same variable?

Tags: c++, string, double

I'm learning c++, and an working through some example exercises. In particular this one takes in command line arguments and then does math operations on them such that if I type

```
./ex1 sum 1.0 2.0 3.0
```

It should sum the numbers up. My code goes something like this:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    double print_val;
    //if we want a sum
    print_val = sum(argc, argv);
    cout << print_val << endl;
}
```

Then, later, I have

```
double sum(int argc, char* argv[]){
    double return_val = 0;
    for(int i =2; i< argc; i++){
        return_val += strtod(argv[i], &argv[i]);
    }
    return return_val;
}
```

For some reason though, I only get 0s out. When I put debugging in, I can SEE that strtod is returning a double via

```
cout << strtod()
and
cout << strtod() + 1.0
```

They both yield expected results, but if in the for loop I put in

```
cout << return_val
```

After each assignment to it, It comes out as 0. I've even tried initializing it to `return_val` to 1.0 to no avail (the same line outputs 1 each time).

I originally had this code in main, and it worked. I copy/pasted it to this function and now it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

The full file, as it currently stands (with lots of debug features) (sorry the indentation is wonky, i'm also learning vim for the first time, and it looks right in vim): http://paste.ubuntu.com/8320413

Comment: Please ensure that the code in your question reflects your actual code, otherwise it's confusing.

Comment: Why are you modifying `argv[i]` in your call to `strtod(argv[i], &argv[i])` ? You should just pass NULL for the second parameter, i.e. `strtod(argv[i], NULL)`.

Comment: You've got a good opportunity to fix this ancient C bug.  Change the function declaration to double sum(int argc, const char* argv[]) and the compiler will tell you what you did wrong.

Comment: If it worked in main, it is incredibly likely that you didn't pass the right parameters to the new function.

Comment: what's wrong with `stod`

Comment: @PaulR I modified it because I'm brand new to C/C++ and found an example online that did just that.

Comment: @musher: well I think this is what they call a "teachable moment", i.e. don't just blindly copy and paste code from the internet without first taking the time to understand what it does.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
strtod(argv[i], &argv[i])
```

This converts `argv[i]` to a `double` and stores a pointer to the rest of the string in `argv[i]`. In your case, it's going to be an empty string since the entire string is used for the conversion.

That means that you would only be able to call this once with each value of `i`. If some part of your debugging code did the call this way, then all later calls with the same `i` will be trying to extract a `double` from an empty string and fail.

There's no need for this, just pass a null pointer for the second argument:

```
strtod(argv[i], nullptr) // C++11
strtod(argv[i], NULL) // pre-C++11
```

I [get the correct output](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6c24384c171bd216) once I made this change.

---

Note that this doesn't handle error cases such as when `argv[i]` cannot be converted at all. To detect that, you can:

- pass the address of a local variable as the second parameter to `strtod`:

  ```
  char *optr;
  double result = strtod(argv[i], &optr);

  // This checks if at least some part of the string has been converted
  // Check *optr != '\0' instead for whether the entire string is converted
  if(optr == argv[i]) { 
      // Handle failure...
  }
  ```
- Use `std::stod` (for C++11 or later), which throws an `std::invalid_argument` exception if no conversion can be performed.

Comment: Yep, that does indeed fix it. I should probably read up on c++ operators before I try delving more into working with the language

Comment: Actually, he should pass a pointer to a local variable, and check that `strtod` actually did use all of the characters.  Otherwise, an argument like `"abc"` will be treated as 0, rather than generating an error.

Comment: It would be better to use `stod` (exception on failure) rather than passing a nullpointer (ignore failure).